# number under chrome extension icon

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome-extension, icons

Can someone tell me how can I put function chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText to show number under icon in chrome extenstion. The number needs to be taken from variable from php file, but it can be in another file than chrome.php.
My files:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Mysite",
  "version": "0.9.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My Description.",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "chrome.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.mysite.com/",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

chrome.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>MySite</title>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<div id="resultado" style="font-family: Arial;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest;
chrome.tabs.query({
 active: true,
 currentWindow: true
}, function(tab) {

tabUrl = tab[0].url;
XHR.open('GET', 'http://www.mysite.com/chrome/chrome.php?tab=' + tabUrl + '', true);
XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(4 == this.readyState) {
    var status = this.status;
    if(400 > status) {
      var responseText = this.responseText;
      if(responseText) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = responseText;

      }
    }
  }
};
XHR.send();
});
};
```

Comment: Is this code in your background page? Where is it located? Does using `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(responseText)` inside your `readystatechange` handler not work?

Comment: I have edited my post with adding all files which I have got (just without PHP file, as I don't think that PHP file is important in this question).

Answer (score 0):

> "permissions": [
>       **"http://www.mysite.com/"**,
>       "tabs"   ]

The match pattern is incorrect. Use *"http://www.mysite.com/*"* instead. Take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html for more information.